# pip install requests exception and pip install beautifulsoup4 exception

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup, pip, python-requests

I have installed Python 3.4.1 on Windows 7, pip included and during install have selected add python.exe to PATH.

When running pip install requests I get:

```
    C:\Python34>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\python3
4\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
  Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 370, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip_build_User\\pip\\pip\\_vendor\\distlib\\w32.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 302, in run

    requirement_set.cleanup_files(bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1333, in cleanup_files
    rmtree(dir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 43, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 477, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 372, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 53, in rmtree_errorhand
ler
    (exctype is PermissionError and value.args[3] == 5) #python3.3
IndexError: tuple index out of range

  Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\User\pip\pip.log
```

When running pip install beautifulsoup4 I get:

```
    C:\Python34>pip install beautifulsoup4
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_User\beautif
ulsoup4\setup.py) egg_info for package beautifulsoup4

Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py install for beautifulsoup4
    Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
    Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
    Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
    Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma

Successfully installed beautifulsoup4
Cleaning up...
  Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 370, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip_build_User\\pip\\pip\\_vendor\\distlib\\w32.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 302, in run

    requirement_set.cleanup_files(bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1333, in cleanup_files
    rmtree(dir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 43, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 477, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 367, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 372, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 53, in rmtree_errorhand
ler
    (exctype is PermissionError and value.args[3] == 5) #python3.3
IndexError: tuple index out of range

  Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\User\pip\pip.log

C:\Python34>
```

I am wondering what those Exceptions mean?

Have the packages really successfully installed like given in the log and will they run fine or am I doing something wrong.

Why the exceptions and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Installing beautifulsoup is a PITA, whatever the version is... But in this particular context, that may not be the issue. Is the console running with administrative privileges?

Comment: @BartoszKPc I personally have no issues installing bs4 with pip on Windows.

Comment: Yes, not running the cmd as admin was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the permission exceptions means that your command prompt has no administrator rights.

Run the command prompt as Administrator (search for cmd in start menu, right click, Run as Administrator). If that doesn't work, try reinstalling pip; the file permissions things might have been screwed up somehow.

Comment: Ran the cmd as admin and no exceptions in both cases. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this solution... Was badly stuckup due to permissions issue. +1 for that..